# How to read a hexdump byte by byte in bash or awk?

Tags: bash, text-processing, shell-script, awk, tcpdump

This is the hexadecimal output of an IPv6 TCP packet captured with `tcpdump`:

```
 6000 0000 0018 0620 0000 0000
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 *0026 0026
 0000 0001 0000 0002 {5}412 0065 0034 0000*
 6162 6364
```

The packet itself is between the `*`s above. The `{5}` represents the packet length in 32-bit words (so it's 5 words long -- 20 bytes). I need to extract tcp header from this info using a bash/awk script, so the script needs to find the length byte and use it to know how much further to read. How can I do that in bash or awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a job for Perl or Python, but you can do it with pure bash. Warning: untested.

```
ipv6_packet='6000 … 6364'
ipv6_packet=${ipv6_packet,,?}               # normalize hexadecimal digits to lowercase, just in case
ipv6_packet=${ipv6_packet//[!0-9a-f]/}      # remove whitespace and everything else that isn't a hex digit
tcp_packet=${ipv6_packet:80}                # all but the first 40 bytes (IPv6 header)
((tcp_data_offset=0x${tcp_packet:24:1}*4))  # data offset (25th nybble), converted from words to bytes
tcp_header=${tcp_packet:0:$tcp_data_offset} # that's the TCP header (still in hexdump form)
```

Or for short:

```
ipv6_packet=${ipv6_packet,,?}; ipv6_packet=${ipv6_packet//[!0-9a-f]/}
tcp_header=${ipv6_packet:80:$((0x${ipv6_packet:104:1}*4))}
```